# How can I have nginx serve Wordpress at /blog, without proxy_pass?

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I've posted [this question on WP.SE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191747/how-can-i-have-nginx-serve-wordpress-at-blog/), but got no replies. In the meantime I figured a [solution involving `proxy_pass`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191747/how-can-i-have-nginx-serve-wordpress-at-blog/193366#193366), but it comes with a few downsides.

I have a subdomain installation of Wordpress that I'd like to serve instead at `/blog`. This must be an FAQ, but I haven't nailed the search terms for it (`/blog` being so common doesn't help).

Where can I find a full nginx config file and wp-config settings that have WordPress live at /blog? Do I need to alter any WP settings in its MySQL database? Is it practical to move my existing instance, or should I start from scratch?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

If you already changed you site URL, as you stated in the other question, you can try with alias location, inside the existing server block.

It should look something like this

```
location ^~ /blog {
root /var/www/example.com;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;

location ~ \.php {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.*\.php)(.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
 }
}
```

This is assuming your WordPress install is in `/var/www/blog`, if not change accordingly.

You need to check if php5-fpm(assuming you are using this) actually listen on `127.0.0.1:9000`
Most of the time the default socket on Debian/Ubuntu is `unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock`
If you want to be sure what is the socket or change it, take a look at `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`.

You can also take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6155935/1383541)
Please note that in this answer configs are missing `?$args` after index.php and this important for plugins like WooCommerce - they wont work properly without it.

If you want to be sure everything is correct, you can export a dump of your database, and then use find and replace with some text editor the old url with the new one.